# Is it possible to create a OR test with only IFs and equality tests?

Tags: conditional-statements

I'm working with a templating language that is constrained in its ability to handle conditionals. I have `IF`s and I can test for truth.

I know that I can emulate `if A && B` if I use:

```
IF A
   IF B
     // A && B here
   END IF
END IF
```

But is there a way that I can emulate an OR? Asking around my colleagues, nobody can think of a way. Is there a way to demonstrate that it is or is not possible?

#### EDIT

I *could* do it this way:

```
IF A
   IF !B
     // A && !B here
END IF
IF B
  // (A && B + !A && B) here
END IF
```

This simplifies to `A || B` and only runs one of the blocks of code

Comment: If this is Dust, based on the description and your other questions, you have a couple choices-- a context helper, or an `{@any}` block (which is an OR, not an XOR)

Comment: Thanks... this was really a more generic question driven by mustache - so, entirely logicless.
I much prefer dust for the fact that logicless templates just don't cut it sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it you use an extra variable.  Duplicating the code doesn't work, because then it runs twice if they're both true.

```
AorB=false
if A; then  AorB=true;  fi
if B; then  AorB=true;  fi
if AorB; then
    // A || B
fi
```

Also note that our conditionals are testing for truth, not for equality.  Equality is a binary operator, like `A == B`.  You should write it as `NOT(A == 0)` if you want to use *only* equality tests.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question regarding 'equality' and added an example for duplicated code without running it twice.

Comment: oh yeah, nice idea for avoiding running twice without an extra variable to store the condition.  Of course, if you can use "break", "goto", "switch", or "return", or any other un-structured flow control, this would be easier.